# Parsing through HTMLCollection object

Tags: javascript, xml, html-parsing, htmlcollection

I have a xml returned as

XML Document

```
<MESSAGE>
<HEADER>
<LOGIN>005693</LOGIN>
</HEADER>
<SESSION>
<LATITUDE>0.0</LATITUDE>
<LONGITUDE>0.0</LONGITUDE>
<APP>abc</APP>
<ORG>TTT</ORG>
<TRANSACTION>PRELOGIN</TRANSACTION>
<KEY>PRELOGIN</KEY>
<TYPE>PRELOGIN</TYPE>
</SESSION>
<PAYLOAD>
<PRELOGIN>
<ID>005693</ID>
<USERNAME>005693</USERNAME>
<PASSWORD>tech@2014</PASSWORD>
</PRELOGIN>
</PAYLOAD>
</MESSAGE>
```

on writing code

```
var message = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("MESSAGE")
```

I get HTMLCollection Object now how to parse through this .
I need to extract First name and last name from this . Please guide

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Parsing in Javascript in Generic Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800782/xml-parsing-in-javascript-in-generic-mode)

Comment: Please do not repost questions, edit your old one to reflect your own progress on solving the problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: Edited please look into this

Comment: Would you mind to delete the secondary question then?